# SwiftUI: minimumScaleFactor not handling special characters like í or ý

Tags: swift, swiftui

I set the font as 200 and minimumScaleFactor to 0.01. Everything scales perfectly when using english characters. But when I tried with ýúáí or some sentence including these characters, the scaling is not correct. What is even stranger is how sometimes the scaling looks fine in Portrait mode and not in Landscape and in other cases it is vice versa.

I am using a custom font and I didn't find a way to use .largeFont or some other approach. Does an alternative way exist to what I am trying to achieve?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextScale: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("ýúáí!")
                    .font(.custom("Verdana-Bold", size: 200))
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height/5, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.green)

                Image(systemName: "camera")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 3*geo.size.height/5)
                    .background(Color.blue)

                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "camera")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height/5)
                //.padding(.bottom)
                .background(Color.orange)
            }

            .background(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}
struct TextScale_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextScale()
    }
}
```

Comment: you wrote " Does an alternative way exist to what I am trying to achieve?". the question is: what do you try to achieve?

Comment: make the text fit the frame either by using minimumScaleFactor or with something else

Answer (score 0):

change your layout strategy ... try

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("yáž!")
                    .font(.custom("Verdana-Bold", size: geo.size.height/9))
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.green)

                Image(systemName: "camera")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 3*geo.size.height/5)
                    .background(Color.blue)

                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "camera")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height/5)
                //.padding(.bottom)
                .background(Color.orange)
            }//.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            .background(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}
```